# Connecting to multiple clients TCP modbus

Tags: python, tcp, modbus

I have a working modbus server and client using a python script I run on the ocmputer, it operates by using socket.connect with the client's ip and port to connect and allow for modbus requests to be exchanged.

I do not know how to apply this for multiple ip's. What I want my program to do is connect to 10 different modbus clients and query them all for information.

Is it possible to call multiple socket.connect to open multiple streams? and if so will it function similarly to a serial connection when each client will need a unique slave ID?

edit:

```
#sets all the standard values
PLC1_IP = '10.0.238.34'
PLC1_Port = 504
PLC2_IP = '10.0.188.34'
PLC2_Port = 505


try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except (socket.error, msg):
    print("Unable to create socket. " + msg[1])
    sys.exit()
#connects to the plc using the port and ip    
s.connect((PLC1_IP, PLC2_Port))

PDU = struct.pack(">BHH", Function_Write, coil_number, Coil_On)
MBPA = struct.pack('>HHHB', 100, PLC1_Protocall, PLC1_Length, PLC1_Unit)
s.send(MBPA+PDU)
s.recv(1024)


#insert main code here

#s.close
```

This is the code I am using at the moment to open a single connection and send my modbus packet. If I wanted to open a connection to the second PLC how would I do that?

Comment: if you are calling socket connect ... you are the client ... they are the server .... if you are calling socket accept you are the server and they are the clients.... so Im curious are the other ip's servers or clients?

Comment: Sorry, wrong way around, the other ip's are the servers. What I am running using python is the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_socket(ip):
    s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connecnt((ip,port))
    return s

my_clients = [make_socket(ip) for ip in ip_addresses]

for client in my_clients:
    client.send("Hello")
    print client.recv(100) # or whatever
```

maybe something like that ... its hard without seeing any of your code ...

Comment: I have updated my question with the code used in my python script, the problem arises when I try to send a message to an individual PLC. How do I define which PLC should act upon the message? Is that where the slave number matters?